# R: change order of few columns only based upon another column

Tags: r, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a data.frame as below. For each set of distinct values in the `name` column, I want to reverse order of the `ID` column. I dont want to touch rest of the columns. My data is huge. How should i do this effectively?

```
ID=c(466,469,471,480,509,513,515,517,518,519,520,521,453,455,463,474,477,479,481,482,484,489,496,497,500,503)
name=c(rep("a",12),rep("b",14))
start=c(rep("2/13/2013",12),rep("3/6/2013",14))
end=c(rep("2/20/2013",12),rep("3/13/2013",14))
start=as.Date(start,"%m/%d/%Y")
end=as.Date(end,"%m/%d/%Y")

maint=data.frame(ID,name,start,end)
```

the data looks like below

```
ID  name    start   end
466 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
469 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
471 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
480 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
509 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
513 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
515 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
517 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
518 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
519 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
520 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
521 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
453 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
455 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
463 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
474 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
477 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
479 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
481 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
482 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
484 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
489 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
496 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
497 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
500 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
503 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
```

The final data should look like below

```
ID  name    start   end
521 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
520 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
519 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
518 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
517 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
515 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
513 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
509 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
480 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
471 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
469 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
466 a   2/13/2013   2/20/2013
503 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
500 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
497 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
496 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
489 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
484 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
482 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
481 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
479 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
477 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
474 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
463 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
455 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
453 b   3/6/2013    3/13/2013
```

Comment: In your case you could maybe just do `maint[order(maint$name, -maint$ID),]` Or `data.table::setorder(maint, name, -ID)` if you need efficiency. Or `with(maint, ave(ID, name, FUN = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))`

Comment: i am not sure if the first suggestion will work. Because it will sort start and end date fields as we are sorting ID by descending order

Comment: In that case the third option. Or `library(data.table) ; setDT(maint)[, ID := sort(ID, decreasing = TRUE), by = name]` or similar with dplyr

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure your data frame is sorted by name first. Your example is sorted, but your data maybe not. dplyr solution is probably faster.

For when ID is a date:

```
ID <- as.Date(c(25:50), '1999-1-1')
ID <- sample(ID, length(ID))
name <- c(rep("a",12),rep("b",14))
start <- c(rep("2/13/2013",12),rep("3/6/2013",14))
end <- c(rep("2/20/2013",12),rep("3/13/2013",14))
start <- as.Date(start,"%m/%d/%Y")
end <- as.Date(end,"%m/%d/%Y")

maint=data.frame(ID,name,start,end)

maint$ID <- maint$ID[order(maint$name, -rank(maint$ID))]

head(maint, 50)

           ID name      start        end
1  1999-02-20    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
2  1999-02-17    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
3  1999-02-15    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
4  1999-02-12    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
5  1999-02-11    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
6  1999-02-10    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
7  1999-02-06    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
8  1999-02-05    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
9  1999-02-03    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
10 1999-02-01    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
11 1999-01-31    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
12 1999-01-26    a 2013-02-13 2013-02-20
13 1999-02-19    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
14 1999-02-18    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
15 1999-02-16    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
16 1999-02-14    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
17 1999-02-13    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
18 1999-02-09    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
19 1999-02-08    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
20 1999-02-07    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
21 1999-02-04    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
22 1999-02-02    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
23 1999-01-30    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
24 1999-01-29    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
25 1999-01-28    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
26 1999-01-27    b 2013-03-06 2013-03-13
```

Comment: This should be by group

Comment: in my data, ID column is actually a date field and it is called newstart and i am getting an error. What is going wrong? `Error in `-.Date`(maint$newstart) : 
  unary - is not defined for "Date" objects`

Comment: Deleted my last comment. I was getting rank and order mixed up. For this i think you need to wrap your ID column (that's really a date) in rank. That will give it a unique numeric ID that you can reverse order. Hope this helps.